# pyplot subplots fails with seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

In attempting to plot two histograms with seaborn side by side I am getting the following error:

My code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.distplot(MAPE_per_stock , ax = axs[0,0])
sns.distplot(MAPE_per_stock[start_test:], ax = axs[0, 1])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-212-9c4fad36d97d> in <module>
      1 fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
----> 2 sns.distplot(MAPE_per_stock , ax = axs[0,0])
      3 sns.distplot(MAPE_per_stock[start_test:], ax = axs[0, 1])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

What provoked the exception and how should I correct the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
```

Looking at the `axs`that you create

```
axs.shape

out: (2,)
```

So, an array with two elements along one axis. The individual elements can be accesssed with `axs[0]`, `axs[1]`:

```
axs[0]
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1965b6bc5f8>
```

since there is only one direction in which data is ordered, specifying two positions leads to the error you have been getting:

```
axs[0,1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-aaadfc217757> in <module>
----> 1 axs[0,1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Note that if you create a 2 by 2 grid:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

you actually create a 2 by2 array, which you can index with the scheme in your question.

```
axs.shape
out: (2,2)

axs[1,1]
out: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1965bcd1860>
```